# Dualshock 4 won't turn on outside of steam anymore

Tags: ps4, controllers

I've used my controller fine until I started using it on Steam. I can still use it for Steam, but when I try syncing it back to my PS4 it won't work. I will say I've tried the reset button on the back, nothing. Also it won't turn on unless it's plugged into my PC.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you've lost the pairing with your PS4 system. According to the Sony instructions, you need to pair it by plugging it directly in to the PS4 with a USB cable.  Have you tried this, you don't specifically state that in your question?

http://manuals.playstation.net/document/gb/ps4/basic/usecontroller.html

Comment: This is almost definitely it; I often use my DS4 on Steam, and though it usually stays synced to my PlayStation, I do occasionally have to reconnect it